# which free LDAP server to use?

Tags: java, apache, ldap

I am trying to build a web application that will use an LDAP server on an Apache Tomcat 7.0 . Looking over the internet i have not find sufficient articles to justify why use one rather another server.

So I have turned to the more experienced guys here that have sufficient experience with more than one LDAP server.

My requirements are: To be free, easy to install and use (good gui) and sufficient API's so that i will be able to insert users, groups, perform lookups etc from a java based application. It should also provide a good level of security.

Thank you in advance for your attention

Comment: I will add to all the recommendations for OpenLDAP that an excellent Windows port is available at www.userbooster.de. Been using it for years, zero problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will recommend going with [openLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) as server, [UnboundID](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) as LDAP SDK, [JXPlorer](http://jxplorer.org/) or [ApacheDirectoryStuido](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) as GUI control over the ldap - this covers probably all of your requirements.

All of the above software is free:

- openLDAP is probably the widely used LDAP server, if you don't count ActiveDirectory. It's well documented and can be easily supported.
- the UnboundID lib is the best I have experience with, and in my opinion - most friendly and feature rich lib for LDAP out there at this moment. Check out this [feature comparison matrix](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/advantages/comparison.php).
- the UI tools differ in complexity - JXplorer is the simpler one.

Answer (score 5):

There's plenty of LDAP servers around. I am using [OpenDJ](http://www.forgerock.com/opendj.html), that has been developed on the older [OpenDS](http://opends.java.net/), and I have never had problems on both.

If you like Apache you can use [Apache Directory](http://directory.apache.org/), but perhaps the most famous around is [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/).

Concerning the `API` for accessing to the directory using Java, this is not a feature to be looked for in a particular LDAP server implementation, because it's standard in Java SDK: the magic word is `JNDI`:

> JNDI does for LDAP what JDBC does for Oracle -- it provides a standard API for interacting with naming and directory services using a service provider interface (SPI), which is analogous to an JDBC driver

(source: [LDAP and JNDI: Together forever](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2000/jw-0324-ldap.html), I recommend to check out this excellent tutorial)

Comment: ... what JDBC does for *databases*. Strange statement as originally formulated.

Comment: You are right, that formulation is not appropriate, and your correction sounds much better. Anyway that was a citation... and I think that talking about about JNDI API in this context was the right thing to do, although this hasn't been recognized by the audience...

Comment: I agree with that. I keep reading that I should use a dedicated LDAP client API, and I keep not doing it and using JNDI to do in some cases some fairly curly things, and I keep wondering what the fuss is all about. There are things about LDAP, such as Attribute, that I would do differently if I was doing it from scratch, but it maps 1::1 onto LDAP as far as I've gone, and I've gone pretty far with it.

Answer (score 3):

On a Windows environment, you can also consider using [Lightweight Directory Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754361%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), a small and free (as in beer) LDAP server.

**Pros:**

1. Installation is pretty straightforward
2. Multi master replication out of the box
3. It can chain authentication requests to Active Directory, usign the userProxy or userProxyFull object class.
4. Administrator accounts can be Windows domain accounts

**Cons:**

1. Be prepare to implement password policy yourself. It relies on the effective machine password policy, which might be more strict in a production environment for your administrators than for your users.
2. Ties that part of your infrastructure to Windows.

Comment: This post (and others) would indicate that AD LDS has a licencing cost associated with it? http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1141045

Comment: Yes, but it also says the contrary. We have about 1.2M external users in an LDS and the licensing people are OK with it. It is a government agency that would rather pay or use another vendor than be in the news for breaking the rules. The best advice I can give you is to contact your local MS sales person (we had the in house Microsoft TAM join in). I'm afraid that the front line licensing people don't get this question very often...